# postgis query finding MultiPolygons within lat/lng bounds

Tags: postgis, polygon, st-intersects

### Question Summary

I am trying to find all the `MultiPolygons` within lat/lng bounds, and I am unable to get a valid query. Ultimately I believe I have not transformed the `MultiPolygons` into something i can query correctly, but I might be reaching...

### Question Details

**NOTE**: I have provided all of the **Background Details** of my data at the end of the post, and demonstrated (hopefully) that it is correct and has the appropriate SRIDs .

I have two `GEOMETRY` columns:

```
geom        GEOMETRY(MultiPolygon,2926) => original from the import
geom_google GEOMETRY(MultiPolygon,4326) => created, so i could query
```

Assuming i have the correct data and SRIDs, I am trying to get all the rows that are within a certain bounds

The bounds are coming from a google map getBounds() call, and are:

```
{
    north: 48.04148960598052,   // lat
    south: 47.18983904097505,   // lat
    east: -121.80370233688086,  // lng
    west: -122.65239618453711   // lng
}
```

To simplify:

```
{
    north: 49,   // lat
    south: 47,   // lat
    east: -121,  // lng
    west: -123   // lng
}
```

Points are set as `ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(lng, lat),SRID)`

`ST_MakeBox2D` asks for: `pointLowLeft` and `pointUpRight`, so:

```
pointLowLeft => west(lng) and south(lat)
    ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-123, 47),4326)

pointUpRight => east(lng) and north(lat): 
    ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-121, 49),4326)
```

My Box would then be:

```
ST_MakeBox2D(
    ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-123, 47), 4326),
    ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-121, 49), 4326)
)
```

which when selected shows:

```
BOX(-123 47,-121 49)
```

### Attempts at an Answer

```
select * from "kc"."plss" where ST_Intersects(
    ST_MakeBox2D(
        ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-123, 47), 4326),
        ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-121, 49), 4326)
    ),
    geom_google);
```

which returns:

```
[XX000] ERROR: Operation on mixed SRID geometries
```

I have tried:

```
select * from "kc"."plss" where ST_Intersects(
  ST_Transform(
      ST_MakeBox2D(
        ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-123, 47), 4326),
        ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-121, 49), 4326)
      ),
      4326
  ),
  ST_SetSRID(geom_google, 4326));
```

which returns:

```
[XX000] ERROR: Input geometry has unknown (0) SRID
```

I have also tried:

```
select ST_AsGeoJSON((ST_DUMP(ST_Transform(geom_google,4326))).geom::geometry(Polygon,4326)) from "kc"."plss" where ST_Intersects(ST_MakeBox2D(
    ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-123, 47), 4326),
    ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-121, 49), 4326)
  ),geom);
```

Which is valid, but returns 0 rows

### Actual Question

Can anyone point me to where I am going wrong?

---

### FINAL, CORRECT QUERY:

Here is the final, correct query (helped by @tilt), just so it is clear:

```
SELECT id from "kc"."plss"
WHERE ST_Intersects(
ST_SetSRID(
    ST_MakeBox2D(
        ST_Point(-122.23124645385474, 47.620059604358204),
        ST_Point(-122.20472477111548, 47.64666550757364)
    ),
    4326
),
geom_google);
```

which results in 20 ids:

```
1090,1096,1093,1095,1178,1179,1180,1177,1231,1234,1235,1236,1313,1314,1315,1316,1367,1369,1364,1366
```

or for those of you looking for the polygons, here is my real query:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON((ST_DUMP(geom_google)).geom::geometry(Polygon,4326)) from "kc"."plss"
WHERE ST_Intersects(
    ST_SetSRID(
        ST_MakeBox2D(
            ST_Point(-122.23124645385474, 47.620059604358204),
            ST_Point(-122.20472477111548, 47.64666550757364)
        ),
        4326
    ),
    geom_google);
```

---

### Background Details

The dataset I imported is:

http://www5.kingcounty.gov/sdc/Metadata.aspx?Layer=plss

This data is in http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2926/

I imported it into my db, and created a new column:

```
ALTER TABLE kc.plss ADD geom_google GEOMETRY(MultiPolygon,4326) NULL;
```

Then ran:

```
UPDATE "kc"."plss"
SET  geom_google = ST_Transform(geom,4326);
```

Now if I query:

```
select ST_SRID(geom), ST_SRID(geom_google) from "kc"."plss" LIMIT 1;
```

I get:

```
2926    4326
```

And then if I do:

```
select ST_AsGeoJSON(geom), ST_AsGeoJSON(geom_google) from "kc"."plss" LIMIT 1;
```

I get (truncated, of course):

```
{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[1246963.803,247960.583000004],[1246920.789,246646.928000003],...]]]]}
{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-122.430314129407,47.6685817588591],[-122.430378032134,47.6649787218942],...]]]]}
```

So, things are looking good.

I also added some indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_spatial_geom ON "kc"."plss" using gist(geom);
CREATE INDEX ix_spatial_geom_google ON "kc"."plss" using gist(geom_google);
```

Comment: Compliments on the nicely elaborated question.

Comment: I accept that compliment! ;-) This isn't my first rodeo, and I hoped to get it answered. Nothing beats a well phrased question to get an answer! Thank you for helping.

Comment: for the inner point constructors, you can remove ST_SetSRID calls, and just use ST_Point [like the example in the manual](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeBox2D.html)

Comment: your question should be used as a template on how to properly ask a sound question, with edits, follow ups and good structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that ST_MakeBox2D erases the srid. So you have to do st_setsrid after you did makebox2d (also see the example in the postgis docs: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeBox2D.html

Comment: Indeed you are correct. In fact, I had at one time wrapped ST_MakeBox2D in ST_SetSRID in one the combinations of the queries I had written, but at the time I believe I was failing for another reason (my box was mixing up the points lowLeft and upRight maybe?), and so I had failed for other reasons.